# Xquery with SaxonXQDataSource: NoSuchMethodError

Tags: maven, exception, xquery, saxon, nosuchmethoderror

I'm working on a Xquery JUnit test, there are no errors on code, but when runing this exeption is launched:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.saxon.Configuration.newConfiguration()Lnet/sf/saxon/Configuration;
at net.sf.saxon.xqj.SaxonXQDataSource.<init>(SaxonXQDataSource.java:38)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
at ...cat.udl.eps.softarch.hello.XMLConnectionTest.staticFileTest(XMLConnectionTest.java:85)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
...
```

This is the Test:

```
 @Test
public void staticFileTest() throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, XQException, FileNotFoundException {

    XQPreparedExpression expr;
    XQConnection conn;
    //TODO Change local path file
    InputStream testFile = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\...\\testXML.xml");
    String xqueryString =
            " declare variable $doc external;\n" +
            "for $x in $doc return $x//acte/nom/text()";

    XQDataSource xqds = (XQDataSource)Class.forName("net.sf.saxon.xqj.SaxonXQDataSource").newInstance();
    conn = xqds.getConnection();
    expr = conn.prepareExpression(xqueryString);
    expr.bindDocument(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("doc"), testFile, null, null);

    XQResultSequence rs = expr.executeQuery();
    System.out.println("test:");
    while(rs.next())
        System.out.println(rs.getItemAsString(null));
    assertNotNull(rs);
    conn.close();
}
```

Its possible to be a problem with the libraries? I added Maven: net.sourceforge.saxon:saxon:9.1.0.8
and net.sf.saxon:Saxon-HE:9.4

Comment: The `Saxon 9.1.0.8` does not contain the method in question, nor does the `Saxon-HE:9.4`. Remove both and user a newer version of `Saxon-HE`, preferably the latest. The latest version should contain the method as shown [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.saxon/Saxon-HE/9.6.0-1/net/sf/saxon/Configuration.java#Configuration.newConfiguration%28%29).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Saxon 9.1.0.8` does not contain the method in question, nor does the `Saxon-HE 9.4`. You shouldn't need the former either when you have any of the recent versions of the latter. Remove both and use a newer version of `Saxon-HE`, preferably the latest.

The latest version should contain the method as shown [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.saxon/Saxon-HE/9.6.0-1/net/sf/saxon/Configuration.java#Configuration.newConfiguration%28%29). You can find the version details [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-HE/).

Comment: Removed both and fixed using last version. Thanx for answering early!

Comment: Generally this kind of error is caused by using one version of the called code (in this case Saxon) when you compile your application (that is, the unit test), and a different version when you execute it.